# How to make iMacros fill/access CKEditor rich-text edit field?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, imacros

Hi I am trying to fill a CKEditor rich-text area using iMacros in a website.

Unfortunately it is behind a signup page so i cannot show the specific example.

After googling the problem i came across this solution on a iMacros Wiki.
http://wiki.imacros.net/FAQ#Q:_How_can_I_fill_a_TinyMCE_or_CKEditor_rich-text_edit_field.3F

```
URL GOTO=http://ckeditor.com/demo
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:demo3
URL GOTO=javascript:CKEDITOR.instances.editor2.setData('My<SP>content<SP>filled<SP>by<SP><b>iMacros</b>');
```

This script did not work, probably because it is outdated

I need to know how to figure out this part/sequence

"javascript:CKEDITOR.instances.editor2.setData"

on other CKEditor enabled text fields.

And to find out these values "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:demo3"

I familiar with iMacros but i am very new to Javacript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=http://ckeditor.com/demo
URL GOTO=javascript:CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData('My<SP>content<SP>filled<SP>by<SP><b>iMacros</b>');
```

As I understood, the number `N` of Reach Text Editor instances (`...instances.editorN...`) changes according to some rules. See pop-up hints on ‘Inline editing’ tab of the demo page (http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline).

Comment: I basically used this, but looking at the wysiwyg I got a different editor name than editor1 - one we had set ourselves called 'form_answer' so I ended up with `CKEDITOR.instances.form_answer.setData('My<SP>content<SP>filled<SP>by<SP><b>iMacros</b>')`